# How to make libreoffice look better in KDE Plasma?

Tags: kde, libreoffice, plasma-5

I installed the `libreoffice-kde`,`libreoffice-qt5` packages, and it does not use the KDE themes.

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 and LibreOffice 6.2.4 from the `LibreOffice Fresh` PPA.

I know that I can use the GTK theme, and that looks better than this KDE theme, but is there any way to make the LibreOffice with a KDE theme match the theme of my system?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the appimage of libre office with colibri(SVG) icon theme 
[image]

It looks nice.I'm using latest version of libreoffice 6.3